# Python: Inherit from class and change inheritance structure?

Tags: python

Consider

```
Class A:
    blah blah

Class B:
    blah blah

Class C(A):
    blah blah
```

The class C is in a file I'm not allowed to edit. If I could, I would write

```
Class C(B):
    blah blah
```

instead (i.e. inherit from B instead).
The class C is also modified in a lot of places that I can't identify.
So my idea is to copy the class C, i.e. I construct a fourth class:

```
class D(C):
    pass
```

and then make changes to the class D such that it inherits from B instead (i.e. change the inheritance structure once C has been copied). Is that possible?

Comment: You can't, that not how inheritance works. If you want to do this, it's likely that `C` isn't a [well-behaved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) subclass of `A` in the first place. Can you comment on what your use case is / what problem you're trying to solve by doing this? Someone may be able to suggest an alternative design that better fits your needs

Comment: It's not accurate to say that "C has been copied".  D has a reference to its parent, C.  The class members of C are not copied in to D -- instead, there's a chain of references back up the inheritance chain.

Comment: _The class C is also modified in a lot of places_ - I find that statement confusing. Is it used a a lot of places? Is it used to subclass in a lot of places? Or are a lot of places literally modifying it? Any bit of code could do `A.some_method = other_implementation` which would modify the class for all instances of it and its inheritors. Is that what is happening?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes I think so. The output is different if I copy the code for the class C instead of inheriting from it, which means it's being changed somewhere. The changes are good, but I want it to inherit from B instead of A and I'm not allowed to change C in the file in which it is defined.

Comment: `class D(C, B)` and live with the fact that you get some `A`. Alternately `B(C)` can result in basically the same thing, depending...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using multiple inheritance with mixins, something like:

```
class A:
    blah blah

class B:
    blah blah

class X:
    blah blah

class C(X, A):
    blah blah

class D(X, B):
    blah blah
```

`X` is your original `C`. You use multiple inheritance to combine it with `A` and `B` to create `C` and `D`, respectively.